# Notification bell does not display after deploying to sandbox using salesforce dx

Tags: community, salesforcedx, deployment

We have used Salesforce dx to develop salesforce community and deploy. After retrieving the community files and deploy that into our target sandbox, the notification bell disappears.

However, when I use the same set of code to create a new scratch org, the notification bell displays very well with no issue.

We have also manually compared the settings in both orgs in the community builder and workspace, but seems there is no significant difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if we have any metadata also for notification bell thing. Raising with salesforce would be most that can be done I guess.

Comment: @KiranMachhewar I don't think so because it is one setting in the theme. And the same code base works well for creating a scratch org...

Comment: Ohh..good to know, what if we remove that metadata element and then deploy. Just to understand if that is impacting or not.